# Good algorithm for computing volume or surface area in python

Tags: python, math, numpy, volume, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to compute the volume (or surface area) of a 3D numpy array. The voxels are anisotropic in a lot of cases, and I have the pixel to cm conversion factor in each direction.

Does anyone know a good place to find a toolkit or package to do the above??

Right now, I have some in-house code, but I am looking to upgrade to something more industrial strength in terms of accuracy.

Edit1: Here is some (poor) sample [data](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34398796/Data/test.zip). This is much smaller than the typical sphere. I will add better data when I can generate it! It is in (self.)tumorBrain.tumor.

Comment: You need to define what you mean a bit more clearly. If you data is actually a 3D array, then the volume the entire grid occupies is `nx * dx * ny * dy * nz * dz`, but I'm pretty sure you didn't mean that... Do you want the volume inside an isosurface?

Comment: I THINK that you are correct. It is a X x Y x Z binary array and I want the volume of everything contained in the perimeter of the binary part of it. It is typically (but not always) sphere shaped.

Comment: this sounds like fun, can you post a link to some example data?  just save the numpy array with `pickle.dump`

Comment: I added some sample data for you. Its not very good, I will add more later if you want!

Comment: @tylerthemiller - Just FYI: If you pickle numpy arrays, be sure to specify specify something other than the default ascii protocol.  Otherwise, you'll wind up with a huge file (like your example).  E.g. `pickle.dump(data, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)` Alternately, you can just use `numpy.save`.  Also, we can't load your data because you pickled some sort of `dataStructures` object, and without your code, we can't unpickle it.  Try pickling just the numpy array and a tuple of `(dx, dy, dz)`.

Comment: Since you are dealign with medical images, you should take a look at invesalius -  A Free software for 3d medical imaging written in Python (sponsored by the brazilian government) - it will likely hae the features you need, or allow you to code then in. http://www.softwarepublico.gov.br/ver-comunidade?community_id=626732

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use `VTK`.  (I'm going to use the `tvtk` python bindings for it here...)

At least in some circumstances, getting the area within the isosurface will be a bit more accurate.

Also, as far as surface area goes, `tvtk.MassProperties` calculates surface area as well.  It's `mass.surface_area` (with the `mass` object in the code below).

```
import numpy as np
from tvtk.api import tvtk

def main():
    # Generate some data with anisotropic cells...
    # x,y,and z will range from -2 to 2, but with a 
    # different (20, 15, and 5 for x, y, and z) number of steps
    x,y,z = np.mgrid[-2:2:20j, -2:2:15j, -2:2:5j]
    r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)

    dx, dy, dz = [np.diff(it, axis=a)[0,0,0] for it, a in zip((x,y,z),(0,1,2))]

    # Your actual data is a binary (logical) array
    max_radius = 1.5
    data = (r <= max_radius).astype(np.int8)

    ideal_volume = 4.0 / 3 * max_radius**3 * np.pi
    coarse_volume = data.sum() * dx * dy * dz
    est_volume = vtk_volume(data, (dx, dy, dz), (x.min(), y.min(), z.min()))

    coarse_error = 100 * (coarse_volume - ideal_volume) / ideal_volume
    vtk_error = 100 * (est_volume - ideal_volume) / ideal_volume

    print 'Ideal volume', ideal_volume
    print 'Coarse approximation', coarse_volume, 'Error', coarse_error, '%'
    print 'VTK approximation', est_volume, 'Error', vtk_error, '%'

def vtk_volume(data, spacing=(1,1,1), origin=(0,0,0)):
    data[data == 0] = -1
    grid = tvtk.ImageData(spacing=spacing, origin=origin)
    grid.point_data.scalars = data.T.ravel() # It wants fortran order???
    grid.point_data.scalars.name = 'scalars'
    grid.dimensions = data.shape

    iso = tvtk.ImageMarchingCubes(input=grid)
    mass = tvtk.MassProperties(input=iso.output)
    return mass.volume

main()
```

This yields:

```
Ideal volume 14.1371669412
Coarse approximation 14.7969924812 Error 4.66731094565 %
VTK approximation 14.1954890878 Error 0.412544796894 %
```

Comment: This looks awesome! I will try it out when my boss gets back (I don't even have admin privs here, so I can't install vtk :(    ).

Comment: If you get `traits.trait_errors.TraitError: The 'input' trait of an ImageMarchingCubes instance is 'read only'.` see my update to this answer below (code update for tvtk changes)

Answer (score 1):

The voxels are going to be fairly simple, regular polyhedra, no?  Compute the volume of each one and sum them.

Comment: The main problem for that is that the z-direction is too coarse. We do a kind of shells method to average between the slices, but this is not good enough.

Answer (score 1):

## if you are trying to use Joe's answer above, you'll get:

#### `traits.trait_errors.TraitError: The 'input' trait of an ImageMarchingCubes instance is 'read only'.`

Here is the the required change and a diff showing how to fix it.

Modified Code:

```
import numpy as np
from tvtk.api import tvtk
from tvtk.common import configure_input


def main():
    # Generate some data with anisotropic cells...
    # x,y,and z will range from -2 to 2, but with a
    # different (20, 15, and 5 for x, y, and z) number of steps
    x, y, z = np.mgrid[-2:2:20j, -2:2:15j, -2:2:5j]
    r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)

    dx, dy, dz = [np.diff(it, axis=a)[0, 0, 0] for it, a in zip(
        (x, y, z), (0, 1, 2))]

    # Your actual data is a binary (logical) array
    max_radius = 1.5
    data = (r <= max_radius).astype(np.int8)

    ideal_volume = 4.0 / 3 * max_radius**3 * np.pi
    coarse_volume = data.sum() * dx * dy * dz
    est_volume = vtk_volume(data, (dx, dy, dz), (x.min(), y.min(), z.min()))

    coarse_error = 100 * (coarse_volume - ideal_volume) / ideal_volume
    vtk_error = 100 * (est_volume - ideal_volume) / ideal_volume

    print('Ideal volume', ideal_volume)
    print('Coarse approximation', coarse_volume, 'Error', coarse_error, '%')
    print('VTK approximation', est_volume, 'Error', vtk_error, '%')


def vtk_volume(data, spacing=(1, 1, 1), origin=(0, 0, 0)):
    data[data == 0] = -1
    grid = tvtk.ImageData(spacing=spacing, origin=origin)
    grid.point_data.scalars = data.T.ravel()  # It wants fortran order???
    grid.point_data.scalars.name = 'scalars'
    grid.dimensions = data.shape

    iso = tvtk.ImageMarchingCubes()
    configure_input(iso, grid)  # <== will work
    # iso = tvtk.ImageMarchingCubes(input=grid)
    mass = tvtk.MassProperties()
    configure_input(mass, iso)
    # mass = tvtk.MassProperties(input=iso.output)
    return mass.volume


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Diff of changes I made

```
2a3,4
> from tvtk.common import configure_input
> 
6c8
<     # x,y,and z will range from -2 to 2, but with a 
---
>     # x,y,and z will range from -2 to 2, but with a
8c10
<     x,y,z = np.mgrid[-2:2:20j, -2:2:15j, -2:2:5j]
---
>     x, y, z = np.mgrid[-2:2:20j, -2:2:15j, -2:2:5j]
11c13,14
<     dx, dy, dz = [np.diff(it, axis=a)[0,0,0] for it, a in zip((x,y,z),(0,1,2))]
---
>     dx, dy, dz = [np.diff(it, axis=a)[0, 0, 0] for it, a in zip(
>         (x, y, z), (0, 1, 2))]
24,26c27,30
<     print 'Ideal volume', ideal_volume
<     print 'Coarse approximation', coarse_volume, 'Error', coarse_error, '%'
<     print 'VTK approximation', est_volume, 'Error', vtk_error, '%'
---
>     print('Ideal volume', ideal_volume)
>     print('Coarse approximation', coarse_volume, 'Error', coarse_error, '%')
>     print('VTK approximation', est_volume, 'Error', vtk_error, '%')
> 
28c32
< def vtk_volume(data, spacing=(1,1,1), origin=(0,0,0)):
---
> def vtk_volume(data, spacing=(1, 1, 1), origin=(0, 0, 0)):
31c35
<     grid.point_data.scalars = data.T.ravel() # It wants fortran order???
---
>     grid.point_data.scalars = data.T.ravel()  # It wants fortran order???
35,36c39,44
<     iso = tvtk.ImageMarchingCubes(input=grid)
<     mass = tvtk.MassProperties(input=iso.output)
---
>     iso = tvtk.ImageMarchingCubes()
>     configure_input(iso, grid)  # <== will work
>     # iso = tvtk.ImageMarchingCubes(input=grid)
>     mass = tvtk.MassProperties()
>     configure_input(mass, iso)
>     # mass = tvtk.MassProperties(input=iso.output)
39c47,49
< main()
---
> 
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     main()
```

Itemized list of changes:

- Ran it through 2to3 so it can be run in python 3
- Fixed the code for PEP8 compliance according to autopep8 (syntax, length, spacing changes)
- Import configure_imput due to [These changes in TVTK (Github code change)](https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/blob/master/tvtk/common.py#L79)
- Modify the `input=` kwarg in the `ImageMarchingCubes` constructor
- Modify the `input=` kwargs in the `MassProperties` constructor
- Wrap the call to main() in a direct call (to prevent execution if imported) #BestPractices